# Where returns column name along with value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Here is my code:

```
<%= DimensionVersion.where(:dimension_id => 1).select("name") %>
```

I expect to get a list of dimension version names where :dimension_id => 1. There are four in the database.

Instead I get this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x3d351c8>
```

EDIT:

I figured out how to return what I wanted (sort of) with this:

```
<%= DimensionVersion.select("name").where(:dimension_id => 1).all %>
```

Which returns:

```
[#<DimensionVersion name: "Default">, #<DimensionVersion name: "Test1">, #<DimensionVersion name: "Test2">, #<DimensionVersion name: "Test3">]
```

However, I don't want it returned with `#<DimensionVersion Name: ... >`. I tried removing `=` from the leading tag, but then nothing returned.

Answer (score 2):

```
DimensionVersion.where(:dimension_id => 1).select("name")
```

I think you need the pluck method.

Rewrite the above as:

```
DimensionVersion.where(:dimension_id => 1).pluck(:name)
```

Similarly even a higher level construct like collect can be used as:

```
DimensionVersion.where(:dimension_id => 1).collect(&:name)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: They can but it's certainly a bad practice, you load the whole thing just to throw almost everything away.

Comment: When using pluck the query hitting the database would look something like this:
`SELECT name FROM "dimension_versions" WHERE "dimension_versions"."dimension_id" = 1;`

Comment: Pluck works, but not for more than one column (unless I just don't know the syntax, but I've tried `pluck(:col1, :col2)`, `pluck ([:col1, :col2])`.

Comment: I am talking about the `collect` method.

Comment: Oh yes, the collect method is definitely wasteful. But it overcomes the limit of pluck to select only a single column in ruby:
`DimensionVersion.where(:dimension_id => 1).collect{|dv| {name: dv.name, col2: dv.col2} }`

Answer (score 1):

AR returns `Relation` so that you can chain conditions etc. If you want the actual results, call `#all`, `#first`, `#each`,... on it:

```
DimensionVersion.where(:dimension_id => 1).select("name").all
```

> Querying with rails is such a pain in the butt I'm about to abandon the whole framework and go back to php.

You might want to read the guides: [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: Sadly am I but a dense man, so no matter how many times I read and search the guides, I can't get it all to stick.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of the column names by using the collect method like so:

```
DimensionVersion.select("name").where(:dimension_id => 1).all.collect { |d| [d.name]}
```

Comment: Much shorter to say `...collect(&:name)` as Gaurav stated. I might also use the shorter `Hash` syntax, `...where(dimension_id: 1)`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Is there any way to pass two columns into collect, e.g., `...collect(&:name, :id)`. That didn't work for me. But using `..collect { |d| [d.name, d.id]}` did work.

Comment: Uh, no; I didn't see anything regarding collecting anything beyond the name, as in the code in your answer. Also, you're actually collecting an array of name-in-an-array instead of just an array of names. Consider taking a step back and picking up some Ruby, it'll make Rails quite a bit easier to understand.